# How to style TextField in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-material-ui-textfield) package to implement an `OutlineTextField` in my `React native` app.

The problem is that I can't change certain styles like `borderColor / borderRadius`

Here is my current code

```
<OutlinedTextField
    secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry ? isHidden : false}
    ref={textFieldRef}
    inputContainerStyle={[styles.textInput, hasError && styles.errorInput]}
    containerStyle={{height: 56, borderRadius: 8}}
    labelTextStyle={styles.labelStyle}
    onChangeText={handleChange}
    onBlur={() => {
      setFieldTouched(name);
      onBlur(name);
    }}
    {...inputProps}
    label={
      <Text>
        {label}
        {required && (
          <>
            &nbsp;
            <Text style={styles.requiredStar}>*</Text>
          </>
        )}
      </Text>
    }
    errorColor={'red'}
    error={hasError}
  />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     textInput: {
     width: '100%',
     backgroundColor: 'white',
     padding: 0,
     margin: 0,
     borderRadius: 8,
},
})
```

And here is the result
[image]

What I want to achieve is the style of the first google button(from the provided image) => remove gray outline and give valid border radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove border line, set `lineType` prop to `none`.

You can also set `lineWidth` [props](https://github.com/gabrieldonadel/rn-material-ui-textfield#properties) to achieve same effect.

```
<OutlinedTextField
  lineType="none"
  // lineWidth={0}
  // activeLineWidth={0}
  // disabledLineWidth={0}
  ...
/>
```